# How to create a dynamic jquery data table with json data and ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

Im trying to create a dynamic data table with jquery and json. Im trying to exact the keys and set them as headers and then the values in the keys as rows in the table.

So far my code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#action-button').click(function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1oaye',
      data: {
         format: 'json'
      },
      error: function() {
         $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
        var col = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (var key in data[i]) {
                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }

        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
        var table = document.createElement("table");

        // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
            th.innerHTML = col[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            tr = table.insertRow(-1);

            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = data[i][col[j]];
            }
        }

        // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
      },
      type: 'GET'
   });
});
</script>
```

but I keep getting an error that reads:

```
(index):80 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

[My JSON data structure](https://api.myjson.com/bins/1oaye)

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpLcfw7p/)

How do I create a dynamic data table just based on the json data returned setting everything from the table headers to the values in the table?

Comment: If 80 is a line number which line is it in your posted code?

Comment: I just changed the last `div` to `<div id="showData"></div>` and that seems to fix the problem? See [this update to the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpLcfw7p/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made two modifications in your code and it seems to be working after that.

1) Added a div with id 'showData' after div 'info'.

```
<div id="showData">
</div>
```

2) Enclosed   $('#action-button').click(function() in $(document).ready(function().

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#action-button').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1oaye',
            data: {
                format: 'json'
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
                var col = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    for (var key in data[i]) {
                        if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                            col.push(key);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
                var table = document.createElement("table");

                // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

                var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

                for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
                    var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
                    th.innerHTML = col[i];
                    tr.appendChild(th);
                }

                // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    tr = table.insertRow(-1);

                    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                        var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                        tabCell.innerHTML = data[i][col[j]];
                    }
                }

                // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
                var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
                divContainer.innerHTML = "";
                divContainer.appendChild(table);
            },
            type: 'GET'
        });

    });

});
```

The error says that it expecting a div with id 'showData'.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly for data table you need to create the static header portion. I'm sharing my easiest code here.

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="margin-top:20px;">
    <table id="tblPatientDiagnosed" class="table table-vcenter table-responsive table-condensed table-bordered display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center" width="20%">Consultant Id</th>
                <th class="text-center" width="30%">Consultant Name</th>
                <th class="text-center" width="30%">Patinet Name</th>
                <th class="text-center" width="20%">No. of time seen</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>            
    </table>
</div>
```

This is my static head of data-table.

Now in the document ready function you need to initialize it.

```
var tblPatientDiagnosed = '';
$(document).ready(function() {

  tblPatientDiagnosed = $('#tblPatientDiagnosed').DataTable({
    "bPaginate": true,
    aaSorting:[],
    "processing": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
  });

  $("#action-button").on('click',function(){

  tblPatientDiagnosed.fnClearTable();//fisrtly clearing data-table data if exist

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: "controllers/admin/add_treatment.php",
    datatype:"json",
    data: postData,

    success: function(data) {            
        var parseData = JSON.parse(result);
        var datalength = parseData.length;
        for(var i=0; i < datalength; i++){
            var staffId = parseData[i].consultant_id;
            var staffLength = staffId.length;
            for (var j=0;j<6-staffLength;j++) {
                staffId = "0"+staffId;
            }
            staffId = staffPrefix+staffId;
            tblPatientDiagnosed.fnAddData([staffId,'data1','data2','data3']);//write the varibale or data you got from ajax
        }
    }
  }); 
});
```

fnadddata add row

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

    function createdynamictable(yourdata)
    {

        //the parameter must be a json data

        var parsedata = JSON.parse(yourdata)        
        var table = document.createElement("table");

        for (var i = 0; i <= parsedata.length; i++)
        {
            tr = table.insertRow(-1);

            for (var key in parsedata[0])
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                   //Inserting columns fields to the table
                    var trCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                    trCell.innerHTML = key;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Inserting table values to the table
                    var trCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                    trCell.innerHTML = parsedata[i-1][key];
                }

            };

        }


        var div = document.getElementById("showtable");
        div.innerHTML = "";
        div.appendChild(table);

    }
</script>

</head>


<body>


<div id="showtable"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

***How to generate a table with dynamic column titles and data from ajax JSON response.***

```js
//Javascript code

    $.ajax({
        "url": SitePath + "/Attendance/getEmployeeMonthYearlyReport",
        "data": {
            MonthYear: $("#txtEmpMonth").val()
        },
        "type": "GET",
        "dataType": "JSON"
    }).success(function (response) {
        var objData1 = JSON.parse(response);
        var myList = objData1.outdata.Table[0];
        var tableHeaders = '';
        var tableBody = '';
        $.each(myList, function (k, v) {
            tableHeaders += "<th>" + k + "</th>";
            tableBody += "<td>" + v + "</td>";
        });
        $("#tblid").append('<thead><tr>' + tableHeaders + '</tr></thead>');
        $("#tblid").append('<tbody><tr>' + tableBody + '</tr></tbody>');
    })
```

```html
@* Html code *@

<table class="table-striped table-bordered" id="tblid"  align="center" width="100%"></table>
```